# How to define multiple optional variables in the URL?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In django doc proposed instead GET method use urlpatterns, and made ​​convenient way to handle these variables. But if at least one of the variables is not necessary I'll have to write more lines in url.py. I like that I can avoid this?

Example:
If I want to take a sample of posts in a given year, in urlpatterns I should add something like this:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'news.views.show_archive'),
```

> url: .../articles/1994/

If I want to make the sample positions for a particular month a specific year, in urlpatterns I should add something like this:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 'news.views.show_archive'),
```

> url: .../articles/2003/03/

But if I want to see the records of all the years created particular month of year I have to add also this line:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 'news.views.show_archive'),
```

> url: .../articles/03/

But I would like to do only one line that specifies the maximum set of variables, but that would process any of these URL. 
To be honest I'm not sure that this is possible.

Comment: Can you provide your code examples?

Comment: You could always implement a custom router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexps can have optional parts, and view functions can have optional arguments. Also, you can still use querystrings (through `request.GET`) for what has no business being part of the URL (like query terms for a "search" view, ordering and filtering for a listing view, etc).

The point of using urlpatterns instead of querystrings is to build clean "semantic" urls, ie `/blog/posts/<post_id>/` instead of `/blog/posts/?post_id=<post_id>`.

Comment: I'm "not good" in regexp. How do I specify that a certain part is optional?

Answer (score 0):

you could try like this

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 'news.views.show_archive'),


def show_archive(request,year=None,month=None):
    if year and month:
       .....................
    elif year:
       .....................
    elif month:
        ....................
```